# Vtiger login error in version 6.10

Tags: crm, vtiger

I am using vtiger CRM 6.1.0 and installed it correctly
But after login i am getting this error

> {"success":false,"error":{"code":"Illegal request","message":"Illegal request"}}

How to resolve this error as i did not get any solutions from their forums

Answer (score 3):

Official answer from Vtiger developers: Make sure your `$site_URL` in `config.inc.php` is configured same as CRM accessing URL. Difference in this leads to error reported.

Source: http://trac.vtiger.com/cgi-bin/trac.cgi/ticket/8237

Answer (score -1):

The following link will take you to an answer that is supposed to allow for access from multiple locations. Simple example is LAN where you would access via IP address and external via URL.

This is a security measure to prevent csirf attacks.

I am trying to figure out if all modifications go into the resource.php or if the alt_SITE_URL goes into the config.inc.php and the balance goes into the resource.php file.

see:
https://www.vgsglobal.com/blog/vtiger-illegal-request-error/

Answer (score -1):

I recently installed versions 6.2 and 6.4. Each one was a fresh install with the same problem. The official answer did not work for me either.

Also one of the problems that I encountered at login was:

```
{"success":false,"error":{"code":"result is not an object","message":"result is not an object"}}
```

The solution that did the trick was to add a column `is_owner` in the database.

```
ALTER TABLE vtiger_users ADD is_owner VARCHAR (10)
```

Comment: "Illegal request" is NOT "result is not an object".